# phpseclib - Testing SFTP connection failed

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to test sftp connection using PHPSECLIB library, for some servers its connecting and for some connections it throws error,

**"unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 1"**

Code:

```
include('protected/vendor/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');                 
$sftp = new Net_SFTP($dmmodel->host);
$loggedIn = $sftp->login($dmmodel->username, $dmmodel->password);
```

Can anyone provide me an idea to resolve this error ?

Comment: Can you connect to those SFTP servers using any SFTP client running on the same machine as your PHP code?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/669

Comment: @MartinPrikryl its working in filezilla

Comment: @JasminMistry i need to update phpseclib to latest version ?

Comment: You need to use the latest version of phpseclib no matter what. It's security software!

Comment: yes you have to

Comment: As Jasmin Mistry's link kinda hints at there hasn't been a report of this issue since 1.0.10 (latest version is 1.0.15). If you are on the latest version and still having this issue I'd suggest posting the server logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and `echo $ssh->getLog();` at the bottom.